# How to set different provisioning profiles for different targets using Xcode Build

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins, devops

I have one iOS Application with multiple targets due to extension implementation. I was successful in setting provisioning profile via xcodeBuild/Xcode Plugin of Jenkins for single targets.

How to set different provisioning profiles for different targets using Xcode Build at a time?

how to achieve this via Xcode build/Xcode Plugin of Jenkins or via any shell scripts?

Answer (score 0):

For multiple target, you need to create seprate job for each target. And make build (IPA) based on **Xcode Schema File** in xcode plugin.

And make sure as you commit your code, set adhoc/appstore provisioning profile in code signin as per your requirement. After set provisioning profile for your required env. commit your project.pbxproj.

And put your all provisioning profile under,

**Users/Shared/jenkins/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles**

So, as your job running, it will automatically takes provisioning profile as per your **Xcode Schema File** name.

Comment: Interesting. I never heard of such "Xcode Schema File". Could you please elaborate a bit more on that? Is that a plugin?